# How do you disable the Fax Service in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, fax

I occasionally get a loud tone on the phone when I auto-dial a number with my contact manager. Today I also got a fax tone and realized (correctly, I hope) that the tone is probably something with with the fax.

If I disable it, will I be able to still manually receive a fax?

I'd like to disable it. It would be ideal if I could still manually RECEIVE a FAX (although I do that so rarely it's not a big need).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can uninstall the Feature:

Control Panel (icon view) > Programs and Features > Turn Windows Features On or Off

Scroll down to "Print and document services", un-tick :Windows Fax and Scan" then hit OK
.

Or, go to Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Services  and disable "Fax" Service, to disable it, double click "Fax" then set the "Start Up Type" to "Disabled" hit the "Stop" button if it is available, then hit OK

FYI, if you choose the second option above (disabling rather than uninstalling) you can still manually receive a fax. In Windows 7 click START >type  FAX and choose "Scan and FAX console".